# Troubleshooting Slow Craft Website - New Relic

Tags: performance, craft-pro

I am troubleshooting a client website and I have installed new relic on VPS.

Summary:
RESP. TIME = 12,300ms
USER CPU BURN = 7,000ms (56.9%)
SYSTEM CPU BURN = 115ms (0.935%)

`Slowest components  Count   Duration    %
YiiBase::autoload   116     2,570 ms    21%
Craft\ElementsService::buildElementsQuery   175 1,960 ms    16%
Craft\ElementsService::findElements 175 1,690 ms    14%
Craft\BaseElementModel::setContent  153 1,300 ms    11%
__TwigTemplate_8a189a6b8bb1cda953a4a38f8aa3c4ccaccd30c1b5a2b790673a05284bb0de6b::block_menu 1   519 ms  4%
Composer\Autoload\includeFile   19  432 ms  4%
Remainder   1   3,840 ms    31%
Total       12,300 ms   100%`

[image]
I have attached a trace.[image]

It looks like a lot of time is spent on autoload. Any ideas what will cause this? Or what should I be looking at to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where the first set of data you posted is coming from, but in the attached stack trace autoloading is only `.54%` of the total request.

Whatever template(s) you're rendering account for `65%` of the request (for a total of 8 seconds), so I'd start inspecting there.

Loading all of the plugins you have installed is about `10%` (which accounts for about 1.3 seconds of the request), so I'd investigate those as well.

Comment: The information about 21% being Yii autoload comes from APM Summary. I have edited the question added image

Comment: Those are summary stats across all of your requests.  Focus on the stack trace which is for the one slow-running 12 second request.